# Erlang debugging: Natively compiled modules breaking tools like recon and redbug

Tags: debugging, erlang, trace, hipe

I'm using `erlang 17.3` and can confirm that tracing tools like `redbug` and `recon` do not work on modules compiled with `+native` flag. Is this expected ? I can't find any documentation on the web that would confirm this behavior. If it's not a bug, then i'd like to know my options of debugging `HiPE` compiled code in anger.

Answer (score 0):

Tracing does not seem to be supported by the native compiler according to [its doctumentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/HiPE_app.html#feature-limitations):

> **Tracing**
>   Erlang call trace is not supported by HiPE. Calling erlang:trace_pattern({M,F,A}, ...) does not have any effect on HiPE compiled modules.